# VS Code: why is Python dataclass not inheriting the parent's attributes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I am new to OOP, often a big pain as things aren't explained clearly and have weird behaviours.

One frustrating example in Python 3.9.13:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    city: str
    age: int
    
@dataclass   
class Student(Person):
    grade: int
    subjects: list
```

I typed:

```
s = Student()
```

getting, as expected:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 1
----> 1 s = Student()

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'grade' and 'subjects'
```

What's unexpected: why does it not say that `name`, `city`, and `age` are also required?

[image: An example where I try to assign the values to all attributes.]

Comment: Statically speaking, `Student.__init__` only require 2 arguments. Any additional arguments at *runtime* would be passed on to whichever class's `__init__` method gets invoked by `super().__init__`.

Comment: At run time, I actually get an error indicating all 5 are missing, though.

Comment: Then how come this guy sees them all? Minute 1:15 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yr_PTfYElw8&t=8s&ab_channel=IndianPythonista

Comment: It looks like your Student class isn't inheriting from Person. The behavior shown in the video (and reported by @chepner) is exactly what we would expect to see. If I paste your dataclasses into an interactive Python session, I get the expected behavior. Here's a complete example: https://gist.github.com/larsks/1b137323696b24f812a6d36ff4322bc4

Comment: It makes sense, but why would it not inherit?